# How to replace the word after a number of character count?

Tags: php

I need some help in PHP which ignore the word after 500 character count.

This is my PHP code :

```
if(str_word_count($rsa['content']) > 500){

}
```

I will push this content inside an array and the array already inside a loop. I just no idea how to ignore the word after 500 character count.

can some one help me to solve it? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: do you want to trim by 500 characters or 500 words?

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```
$content = substr($rsa['content'], 0, 500);
```

The way that works is `substr` is the function, `$rsa['content']` is the string value, `0` is where `substr` should start & `500` is the string length you wish to have returned.

That said, it seems you are using [`str_word_count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) which counts words when you mean to use [`strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) instead since that counts characters. Knowing that, I would implement it like this. T :

```
// Assign the value of `$rsa['content']` to `$content`.
$content = $rsa['content'];

// Set a `$content_length` to save yourself typing & logic headaches.
$content_length = 500;

// Check the string length & act on it.
if (strlen($content) > $content_length) {
  $content = substr($content, 0, $content_length);
}
```

But you could probably make it even slicker by using a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) instead like so:

```
// Check the string length & act on it.
$content = strlen($content) > $content_length ? substr($content, 0, $content_length) : $content;
```